# priority queue where recency is a secondary priority?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The following example illustrates what I need.  Say it's raining and I've placed a number of barrels throughout town to gather water.  I don't know exactly the rate at which they'll fill, and they vary in how quickly they gather water.  I don't want one to overflow, because then I lose water.  So if I come upon a barrel and it's full, I want to visit it again soon, because it's manifestly getting more water.  If I come upon a barrel and it's not very full, I don't want to visit it for a while, but I do eventually.

So let's say when I visit a barrel, I get two pieces of information.  How full it is (between 0 and 1), and the current time (time since the POSIX epoch).

I'm not looking for an optimal answer (optimal referring to the solution, not the algorithm).  I'm just looking for a simple solution, probably heap-based, that is better than naively visiting every barrel once before re-visiting.  I want to re-visit the barrels that fill more quickly more often.

I also don't want to indefinitely neglect a slow-filling barrel while over-attending fast-filling barrels.

Thanks

Comment: How much does it cost you to look at barrels? is looking at them take time from you?

Comment: Yes, there is a small cost.  Looking at a barrel is a slightly expensive I/O bound task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a priority queue containing each barrel, where the priority of a barrel is the estimated time at which it will be filled. Repeatedly pop the barrel with the earliest estimated fill time, visit it, and reinsert it with a new estimate.

There are many imaginable ways to estimate. A simple one is to remember the last two times visiting a barrel and the last collection amount and extrapolate linearly.